# Dropdown not working right inside a table cell

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

When I place a bootstrap dropdown inside a table cell, the dropdown shows up away from the cell below the table when I click on the dropdown icon. Any ideas on how to solve?

Please see a demo [here](http://frela.info/rtrunk/tiki-listpages.php). In the actions column on the right, click on the ellipsis (...). The position was set at "absolute" and the dropdown was showing under the table. I changed to "static" so now the dropdown shows in the right place but it opens inside the table cell instead of on top of it, so it changes the row size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's a css issue. Try something like this:

```
.open > .dropdown-menu {
  float: right;
  width: 90%;
}
```

Comment: This didn't totally fix it but you're right that this is not a tablesorter issue - same thing happens in a regular table. Changed the original quesiton and tags accordingly.